# Problems with assigning a Azure policy and multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-policy

I'm having some issues assigning one of the built-in policies with a logAnalytics parameter where there are multiple subscriptions involved. I need to do it with code. Here's how I try to accomplish it.

## Get a reference to the built-in policy definition to assign

```
$definition = Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq 'Deploy Log Analytics agent for Windows VMs' }

$parameter = @{
    logAnalytics = '<resourceId to my logAnalytics workspace>'
}
```

## Create the policy assignment with the built-in definition against your resource group

```
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'Deploy LA Agent Windows VMs' -DisplayName 'Deploy LA Agent Windows VMs' -Scope "/subscriptions/<my subscriptionId" -PolicyDefinition $definition -AssignIdentity -Location 'norwayeast' -PolicyParameterObject $parameter
```

This code works fine if I assign the policy to the same subscription where the logAnalytics workspace is located, but if I scope the policy assignment to another subscription and afterward check the assignment in the portal, the Log Analytics Workspace parameter will be empty.
The service principal that runs these commands is owner of both subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way of applying policies across multiple subscriptions is to make them part of a management group. You can apply a policy to the management group and every subscription which is a member will inherit it.

Further information on management groups can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview

Amended code using management groups:

```
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'Deploy LA Agent Windows VMs' -DisplayName 'Deploy LA Agent Windows VMs' -Scope "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/managementGroup001" -PolicyDefinition $definition -AssignIdentity -Location 'norwayeast' -PolicyParameterObject $parameter
```

**Notes**

- You will need to create a management group and add subscription(s) to it before running any commands.
- Assigning subscription(s) to an existing management group can have adverse effects, check there are no conflicts.
- An error is likely to be generated regarding the length of the names used as they are restricted to 24 characters. You should shorten or abbreviate them.
- I have **not** tested this code so please double-check by reviewing the documentation on Microsoft's site before running in your own environment.